# Why is showoff.io unusably slow on my computer?

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox

I'm attempting to use either [Showoff.io](http://showoff.io) or [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) on my Macbook Air, to make a Rails app running on a [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) VM available for testing on external devices. Other uses with identical hardware on the same network are able to do this successfully using the same Showoff credentials.

On my machine, there is a tremendous delay, usually leading to a timeout, before content is served. Using curl, I can see that the DNS resolves almost immediately, but there will be a delay of several *minutes* before I see a request reach my Rails logs. There will then be another simliar delay before I see content in my browser, and typically only the base HTML is successfully delivered. Subsequent requests for the CSS/images/JavaScripts typically timeout as each of these requests is subject to similar delays.

I am not running a firewall, and my Macbook is more or less set to factory defaults. I've tried this on two different Internet connections, one wired and one wireless. The symptoms are the same for my paid Showoff.io account, a free 5-minute showoff.io account, and a free localtunnel account. I'm completely out of ideas on what I could possibly try next to diagnose this problem.

Can anybody suggest a possible next step for figuring out why I'm experiencing this delay or how I could fix it?

Comment: Look very closely at the very last thing that happens before the delay and the very first thing that happens after it. That should at least give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a resolver named `/etc/resolves/vm`, symlinked to `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/dns/resolver/vm`. This was a legacy from a failed attempt to use [vagrant-dns](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) to manage resolution of hostnames to vagrant boxes, something I've since started using [vagrant-hostmaster](https://github.com/mosaicxm/vagrant-hostmaster) for.

I'm not sure why this was causing severe delays instead of outright failures, but removing the file caused showoff to immediately start working as normal.